# scrape instagram information accounT

Tags: python, pip, telegram-bot

I Made this code in my pc and its worked but when i put it on my VPS it start Making error for no reson i tryed to make it exe and run it on vos but the same problem still happening

```
import telebot
import time
import datetime
from instagramy import InstagramUser
bot = telebot.TeleBot("MY TOken")
xuser = input("put the user")
user = (InstagramUser(xuser))
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start','help'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'_0x0')

count = 0
while True:
    time.sleep(20)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    count += 1
    name = user.fullname
    bio = user.biography
    follorwers = user.number_of_followers
    followings = user.number_of_followings
    posts = user.number_of_posts
    picture_url = user.profile_picture_url
    privetornot = user.is_private
    massge = ' THE acoount \n , name {}\n , Bio {}\n  , followers {} , followings {} , number of posts {} , is privet ? {}\n avater {}\n\n number of the massage {} '.format(name,bio,follorwers,followings,posts,privetornot,picture_url,count)
    bot.send_message(5450253810,massge)
    
bot.polling()
```

Comment: Please provide the traceback for the error in your vps.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems that you need to install these modules in VPS.

```
import telebot
import time
import datetime
from instagramy import InstagramUser
```

Comment: I did had the same problem

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: you did like this? pip install telebot

Comment: Its tele me there a problem with instagramy line number 7 and yeah i install all that thing but its still give me an error

Comment: okay try installing these pip3 uninstall telebot
pip3 uninstall PyTelegramBotAPI
pip3 install pyTelegramBotAPI
pip3 install --upgrade pyTelegramBotAPI